# Codeigniter 3 form validation fails on <select>

Tags: codeigniter-3, codeigniter-form-validation

I have form select with 2 values of 0 and 1

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-3" name="status">
    <option value="1">On<option>
    <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
```

Now in codeigniter controller i set rule to accept only values of 0 or 1, so i used `in_list[]` function, but when i select **Off** i get error ***The Status field must be one of: 0,1.***, and when i select **On** i don't get any error.

Here is controller code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required|xss_clean|in_list[0,1]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
    $data = [
        'error' => true,
        'status_error' => form_error('status')
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: possible a TYPO? `<option value="1">On<option>` should have a closing option, therefore `<option value="1">On</option>`

Comment: @Vickel i checked for typo but it isn't, i have few of those selects and all works except this one, i tried to remove all and just make one, just on that specific is something wrong but no idea what